# How create route between two markers in Ionic 3 with native Google Maps plugin

Tags: ionic3

I need to show the route between two markers in Ionic 3, using the native Google Maps plugin. How can I do that? Or is there any plugin or other method to show the route between two markers?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: nothing else @SetuBasak